# Unable to access models built in Sagemaker from Docker image

Tags: amazon-web-services, machine-learning, aws-lambda, amazon-sagemaker, aws-serverless

I have built a machine learning model from within Sagemaker using an inbuilt algorithm (Blazingtext). I am using a batch inference strategy in my inference code as in:

```
transformer = Transformer(model_name="my_model_name",
                          instance_count=1,
                          instance_type='ml.m4.xlarge',
                          output_path=output_pred_dir
                            )
transformer.transform(data=X_batch_location,
                         data_type='S3Prefix',
                         content_type='application/jsonlines',
                         split_type='Line'
                         )
```

Everything works perfectly when the code is run from within Sagemaker. But now I need to run the inference with Lambda. So I did this by packaging the inference code in a Docker image, saved it to ECR and deployed to Lambda. However, it is unable to do the batch transformation and gives the error:

```
[ERROR] ValueError: Failed to fetch model information for "my_model_name". Please 
ensure that the model exists. Local instance types require locally created models.
```

I have tried to use the arn as in model_name="arn:aws:sagemaker:us-east-1:99999999:model/my_model_name" but it does not work.

Please note the model is saved and available on sagemaker; I see it from the sagemaker management console.

How can I allow the dockerised code to gain access to the model in Sagemaker?

PS i built and run the docker from EC2 from where i pushed the image to ECR

Comment: If I understand correctly you are trying to launch the Batch Transform job in lambda function which is deployed as a container.  If yes, you can use the create transformation job boto3 api to launch the job - https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sagemaker/client/create_transform_job.html